# How can we add embedded resources to a file which is compiled from a source file at run-time

Tags: c#, .net, embedded-resource, csharpcodeprovider

I'm writing a small application which works at compiling a file from a source (.cs) code file using a function:

```
public static bool CompileExecutable(String sourceName)
{
    //Source file that you are compliling 
    FileInfo sourceFile = new FileInfo(sourceName);
    //Create a C# code provider 
    CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
    //Create a bool variable for to to use after the complie proccess to see if there are any erros
    bool compileOk = false;
     //Make a name for the exe
     String exeName = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}.exe",
     System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, sourceFile.Name.Replace(".", "_"));
     //Creates a variable, cp, to set the complier parameters
     CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
     //You can generate a dll or a exe file, in this case we'll make an exe so we set this to true
     cp.GenerateExecutable = true;
     //Set the name
     cp.OutputAssembly = exeName;
     //Save the exe as a physical file
     cp.GenerateInMemory = false;
     //Set the compliere to not treat warranings as erros
     cp.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
     //Make it compile 
     CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, sourceName);
     //if there are more then 0 erros...
     if (cr.Errors.Count > 0)
     {
         //A message box shows the erros that occured 
         MessageBox.Show("Errors building {0} into {1}" +
             sourceName + cr.PathToAssembly);
         //for each error that occured in the code make a separete message box
         foreach (CompilerError ce in cr.Errors)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("  {0}" + ce.ToString());
         }
     }
     //if there are no erros...
     else
     {
         //a message box shows compliere results and a success message
         MessageBox.Show("Source {0} built into {1} successfully." +
             sourceName + cr.PathToAssembly);
     }
     //if there are erros...
     if (cr.Errors.Count > 0)
     {
         //the bool variable that we made in the beggining is set to flase so the functions returns a false
         compileOk = false;
     }
     //if there are no erros...
     else
     {
         //we are returning a true (success)
         compileOk = true;
     }
     //return the result
     return compileOk;
}
```

What i want to achieve is to add user-selected file resources ( images, mp3, avi, ttf,..etc ) which will be added as embedded resources to the being compiled using the function above.

how can we add embedded resources to a file which is compiled from a source file at run-time ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to [create a `.resources` file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbx3z216.aspx) containing the files you want to embed as resources, and then reference the generated resource file in your `CompilerParameter`'s instance using the [`EmbeddedResources`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.embeddedresources.aspx) property.

Follow the directions from *Resources in .resources Files* section of the first link above (the section that refers to [`System.Resources.ResourceWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcewriter.aspx)), which will produce a temporary file. Then based on the code in your question (and the example from the `EmbeddedResources` documentation), you'll reference it with something like:

```
if (provider.Supports(GeneratorSupport.Resources))
{
    cp.EmbeddedResources.Add("pathToYourGeneratedResourceFile");
}
```