# Adding resources and setting Exe description

Tags: c#, codedom

I am generating C# code at runtime and compiling it with the `CSharpCodeProvider` The two problems I'm having are

- How to add resources to the generated exe?
- How to set the executable description (i.e company name and others) to it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here my friend. I think this will sort you out as the guy was having the very same issue:

[How can we add embedded resources to a file which is compiled from a source file at run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234203/how-can-we-add-embedded-resources-to-a-file-which-is-compiled-from-a-source-file)

Comment: How can I set the description of the exe?

Comment: If you're compiling from a source file you can add this at the top of one of the classes: Since you are compiling from a source file, have you tried just adding the Reflection namespace and the version attributes to the top of your .cs file before compiling it?

using System.Reflection;
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Got to work. Needs all such tags.