# CompilerResults Properties error

Tags: c#, winforms, compilation

Here is my codes :

```
  Assembly_Create(Application.StartupPath + @"\Out.exe");

  private static void Assembly_Create(string fileDestination)
   {
        CompilerParameters settings = new CompilerParameters(); //the heart of CodeDOM
        string compilerOptions = "/t:winexe /optimize";

        string icon_name = "my_icon.ico";
        string icon_location = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath.Replace("\\bin\\Release", string.Empty), "images", icon_name);

        compilerOptions += " /win32icon:\"" + icon_location + "\"";

        settings.CompilerOptions = compilerOptions;
        settings.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(new string[] { "Ionic.Zip.dll", "Microsoft.CSharp.dll", ... });
        settings.GenerateExecutable = true;
        settings.WarningLevel = 4; 
        settings.OutputAssembly = fileDestination; 

        //settings.EmbeddedResources.Add();

        string sourceCode = Properties.Resources.Source;
        string assemblyInfo = Properties.Resources.AssemblyInfo;

        CompilerResults results = new CSharpCodeProvider().CompileAssemblyFromSource(settings, sourceCode, assemblyInfo);

        if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
   }
```

---

And here is **Source.txt** in Resources Area :
I've created it by myself and put it in Resources Area.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Ionic.Zip;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;

namespace Game_Setup
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form2 frm = new Form2();
            frm.Show();
        }
    }

    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(98, 211);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    }

    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }

    partial class Form2
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(88, 174);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.textBox1.Text = "salam";
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this.pictureBox1.Image = global::Game_Setup.Properties.Resources.Logo;
            this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 105);
            this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
            this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(250, 143);
            this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // Form2
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            this.Name = "Form2";
            this.Text = "Form2";
            this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form2_FormClosing);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
    }

    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

---

In **Source.txt** i put `Form1.cs` & `Form1.Designer.cs` & `Form2.cs` & `Form2.Designer.cs` & `Program.cs` Files.
Mean i gathered all of them in one file called Source.txt.

---

If i remove **pictureBox1** from Form2 everything is ok and i have no error during compilation and biulding assembly.
But if i keep  **pictureBox1** i have error because of this line :

```
 this.pictureBox1.Image = global::Game_Setup.Properties.Resources.Logo;
```

---

And error is :

> The type or namespace name 'Properties' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Game_Setup' (are you missing an assembly refrerence?)

---

How can i fix this error?
I think i should use this line :

```
//settings.EmbeddedResources.Add();
```

But how can i embed Logo image into the new Assembly and how can i introduce it as pictureBox1 image?

---

I am using visual studio 2012 and here is the picture of Solution Explorer :

[image: Solution Explorer Picture]

Comment: Do not put the code inside auto generated CS file. Init your picture box from other Initialize(..), for example, method.

Comment: it *looks* like you are *writing* the code inside designer.cs file, which is a file generated by visual studio. if so, remove your custom code from that file and assign desired value to the `PictureBox` in some other place.

Comment: In Source.txt i put Form1.cs & Form1.Designer.cs & Form2.cs & Form2.Designer.cs & Program.cs -> i combined all of these files in Source.txt because output assembly needs them and this is not my problem. i can give absolute path to pictureBox1 but i don't want extra files (Logo Image) next Out.exe file.

Comment: MoonLight: What is a Source.txt ??

Comment: here is a related thread :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234203/how-can-we-add-embedded-resources-to-a-file-which-is-compiled-from-a-source-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution :
i added these codes to Assembly_Create() method :

```
    IResourceWriter writer = new ResourceWriter("myResources.resources");
    writer.AddResource("Logo", new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Logo));
    writer.Generate();
    writer.Close();

    settings.EmbeddedResources.Add("myResources.resources");
```

and changed Source.txt file like this :

```
    ResourceManager RM = new ResourceManager("myResources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    this.pictureBox1.Image = (Image)RM.GetObject("Logo");
```

Now every thing is ok and i can use my Out.exe file.
please complete my answer and show us other ways.

Answer (score 0):

You are compiling `Form2` by using `CodeDom`. And you want to display picture, which is resource of application, which performs compiling.

Obviously the easiest is to pass that image as parameter.

To example, it can be a `static` property of `Form2`:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public static Image Image {get; set;}

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.Image = Image;
    }
}
```

It should compile without problem. When you going to use that assembly, simply set `Image` to your resource (not sure, so pseudo-code)

```
dynamic obj = results.CompiledAssembly;
obj.Form2.Image = global::Game_Setup.Properties.Resources.Logo;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i should tell you two things : 1-'System.Reflection.Assembly' does not contain a definition for 'Form2' error | 2-i want to use builded assembly in another system, not in my codes. so filling that property is useless.